# Square root within a printf statement

Tags: java

I am trying to implement a square root formula within a math.random and I can't seem to get it right. If I use straight integers it works, but when I insert the math.sqrt's it throws it off. The program runs but it does not come up with the appropriate random number within the range.

Range for output needs to between:
Square root of 53 = **7.28010989**
Square root of 157 = **12.5299641**

Program as I have it now (Runs but desired output is not there)

```
String two = ("A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: ");
System.out.printf("%s" + Math.sqrt(53) + (Math.random()*(Math.sqrt(157))), two);
```

The desired output should be a number that falls in between the 2 square roots.

Answer (score 3):

I have iterated over the following code 100+ times and all results have been between your requirements of 7.28010989 and 12.5299641

```
String two = "A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: %f";
System.out.printf(two, Math.sqrt(53) + ((Math.sqrt(157) - Math.sqrt(53)) * Math.random()));
```

Example output:

```
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 7.388599
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 8.714860
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 8.905630
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 12.521053
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 12.500423
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 12.420511
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 9.277107
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 11.592966
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 11.888476
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 10.008480
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 11.073415
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 9.020220
A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: 7.348448
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the print f was throwing off the equation. I appreciate it!

Comment: @user5317683 Well, your original equation didn't have the lowerbound of `Math.sqrt(53)` and you were using the `printf` statement incorrectly. You should designate your string first (including the `%f` to denote inserting a double/float), and then after the comma input the operation which will calculate the value for that placeholder. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks Robbins, that link helped out. I appreciate your detailed response

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing the `printf`, and your range is wrong. Try this:

```
System.out.printf("A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: %f",
                  Math.sqrt(53) + Math.random() * (Math.sqrt(157) - Math.sqrt(53)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String two = ("A random Number between Sqrt 53 and Sqrt 157 is: ");
double num = Math.sqrt(53 + Math.random()*(157-53));
System.out.printf("%s" + num, two);
```

I guess this is what you want. Sorry I corrected it now.

Comment: Your code has several compiler errors. You've either got to cast the `Math` operations to `float`, or change `num` to a `double`. Additionally you have an extra `)` in your print statement.